# How to transfer data/state between components where data is stored in an API

Tags: javascript, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework

I'm looking for advice on getting a table to re-render after a successful POST (the table and form are on the same page).  I have data that is being provided to a Table via an API (Django-Rest-Framework), so I don't want to have a callback that checks every second for new data since that would needlessly hammer my API.  The relationship between the components are there is a DataProvider, which is the parent of the Table.  The form is it's own component.  What I think I need to do is have an onClick event on the form submit that will fetch from the API again, and re-render the table.  I'm new to React, and have no idea how to actually do this and I haven't had much success googling around (or only finding examples that have a 1sec callback to update a clock or something).

Here are the 4 files that are interacting:

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import DataProvider from "./DataProvider";
import Table from "./Table";
import Form from "./Form";


class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <DataProvider endpoint="/api/properties/" method="GET" render={(data) => <Table data={data} />} />
                <Form endpoint="/api/properties/" />
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById('app')
);
```

DataProvider.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import cookie from 'react-cookies';

class DataProvider extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: [],
            loaded: false,
            placeholder: "Loading...",
        };
    }

  static propTypes = {
    endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    render: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    fetch(this.props.endpoint,  {
        credentials: 'include',
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': cookie.load('csrftoken')
      },
    })
      .then(response => {
        if (response.status !== 200) {
          return this.setState({ placeholder: "Something went wrong" });
        }
        return response.json();
      })
      .then(data => this.setState({ data: data, loaded: true }));
  }

  render() {
    const { data, loaded, placeholder } = this.state;
    return loaded ? this.props.render(data) : <p>{placeholder}</p>;
  }
}

export default DataProvider;
```

Table.js

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import shortid from "shortid";

const uuid = shortid.generate;

const Table = ({ data }) =>
  !data.length ? null : (
    <div className="column">
      <h2 className="subtitle">
        Your Properties <strong>({data.length})</strong>
      </h2>
      <table className="table is-striped">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            {Object.entries(data[0]).map(el => <th key={uuid()}>{el[0]}</th>)}
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(el => (
            <tr key={el.id}>
              {Object.entries(el).map(el => <td key={uuid()}>{el[1]}</td>)}
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );

Table.propTypes = {
  data: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default Table;
```

Form.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import cookie from 'react-cookies';
import DataProvider from './DataProvider';


class Form extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: "",
            type: "Retail",
            address: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            zip_code: ""
        };

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
        this.handleClear = this.handleClear.bind(this);
        this.handleUpdateTable = this.handleUpdateTable.bind(this);
    }
    static propTypes = {
        endpoint: PropTypes.string.isRequired
    };

    handleClear(event) {
        this.setState( {
            name: "",
            type: "Retail",
            address: "",
            city: "",
            state: "",
            zip_code: ""
            }
        );
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState(
            {[event.target.name] : event.target.value}
        )
    }

    handleUpdateTable(event) {
        <DataProvider endpoint="/api/properties/" method="GET" render={(data) => <Table data={data} />} />
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const { name, type, address, city, state, zip_code } = this.state;
        const property = { name, type, address, city, state, zip_code };
        const conf = {
            credentials: 'same-origin',
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify(property),
            headers: new Headers({
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'X-CSRFToken': cookie.load('csrftoken')

             })
        };
        fetch(this.props.endpoint, conf).then(response =>
            console.log(response),
            );
    }

    render() {
        const { name, type, address, city, state, zip_code } = this.state;
        return (
            <div className="column">
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">Property Name</label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input
                                className="input"
                                type="text"
                                name="name"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={name}
                                required
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">Property Type</label>
                        <div className="select control">
                            <select name="type" value={this.state.type} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
                                <option value="Office">Office</option>
                                <option value="Multifamily">Multifamily</option>
                                <option value="Self-Storage">Self-Storage</option>
                                <option value="Hotel">Hotel</option>
                                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">Address</label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input
                                className="input"
                                type="text"
                                name="address"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={address}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">City</label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input
                                className="input"
                                type="text"
                                name="city"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={city}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">State</label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input
                                className="input"
                                type="text"
                                name="state"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={state}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="field">
                        <label className="label">Zip Code</label>
                        <div className="control">
                            <input
                                className="input"
                                type="text"
                                name="zip_code"
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                                value={zip_code}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div className="control">
                        <div className="buttons is-right">
                            <button type="submit" className="button is-info" onClick={this.handleUpdateTable}>
                                <span>Add Property</span>
                            </button>
                             <button className="button is-danger is-outlined" type="reset" onClick={this.handleClear}>
                                <span>Clear Form</span>
                             </button>
                         </div>


                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default Form;
```

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a place where you need to hold the state of your data outside of your component with something like [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the newly updated [Context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html) in React. Either of these would allow you to set the data in your store and your component would then watch that state. Each time the data is updated React would automatically re-render the table.

Comment: Using redux or another library seems pretty bloated and overkill for something this simple...

Comment: Context is built into react and is pretty easy to work with. Without some state manager the best I can think of is holding some flag in state that when updated to true will tigger the fetch and then after the fetch is complete toggle it back to false.